# Why am I getting discord.py AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trigger_typing'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, attributeerror, converters

I can't figure out why the hell I am getting this error. Everything in the code looks good to me. Maybe it is due to the converters not working but my other commands are working properly.

```
   async def ship(self, ctx: commands.Context, user1: discord.Member = None, user2: discord.Member = None):
        if user1 is None or user2 is None:
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                description=f"please mention two persons or provide two image urls! try: `{self.GetPrefix(ctx)}ship @person1 @person2` or `{self.GetPrefix(ctx)}ship [img url1] [img url2]`",
                color=self.randomcolor()))
        else:
            await ctx.trigger_typing()

            r1 = requests.get(user1.avatar_url)
            with open("images/ship_avatar1.png", "wb") as f1:
                f1.write(r1.content)

            r2 = requests.get(user2.avatar_url)
            with open("images/ship_avatar2.png", "wb") as f2:
                f2.write(r2.content)

            await self.ship("images/ship_avatar1.png", "images/ship_avatar2.png", "images/ship.png")

            embed = discord.Embed()
            embed.set_image(url="attachment://ship.png")

            file = discord.File("images/ship.png", "ship.png")

            await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Mob/cogs/fun.py", line 397, in ship
    await self.ship("images/ship_avatar1.png", "images/ship_avatar2.png", "images/ship.png")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 372, in __call__
    return await self.callback(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Mob/cogs/fun.py", line 387, in ship
    await ctx.trigger_typing()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trigger_typing'
```

Comment: `ctx `  is a string instead of the Context object, if you’re not using cogs don’t add `self` as an argument

Answer (score 2):

I assume this function is not in a class. Therefore, the self value became a Context class and the ctx value became an argument. The error you get is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trigger_typing'" it means that a str object doesn't have access to the function `trigger_typing`. Remove the self value from the  async function will be a quick fix.

Comment: Actually I figured it out myself. It was causing error because I already defined a function named "ship" which was not a command and I was calling that function within the "ship" command function.

Answer (score 0):

The "ship" function which is not a command is already defined in the same class which is being called in the "ship" command function. Renaming the function solved the problem.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct.